# Project layout with Subversion and static resources

Tags: version-control, layout, svn

I'm working on a project which (as usual) contains source code and many static resources like images and generated files (for UI and l10n).

By now, everything is versioned with Subversion, but I think there must be a better way to store the static and generated files and link them on project deployment.

So, in your opinion which option the best?

- Keep everything together.
- Set a different and more appropriate storage (and probably versioning system) for every different kind of file.
- ...

Comment: I would keep it together. Otherwise, you (or another 'new' developer) need to checkout all the different sources, which is more work.

Answer (score 1):

*Generated* files I would `svn:ignore`. As long as they are automatically re-generated if they don't exist (or the generation process is easy to trigger) versioning the generated files would be just clutter.

*Static* files - images, style sheets, etc. - I would keep together, as long as they're not so heavy that they'll slow down the whole process. After all, they are a fixed part of your project.